# How to add a the share 'menu' like this?

Tags: iphone

Does any of you guys know what this 'menu/view' is called and how to implement this?

I have no idea of what the name is, and i have been looking through apples documentation, but i was not able to find it..
[image: What is this menu called?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a `UIActivityViewController`

Find the documentation about it here:

[UIActivityViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks Antonio! - i will accept this answer within 12 minutes :-)

Comment: There's some pretty recent sample code showing some of the more advanced ways to use UIActivityViewController in the [AirDrop Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html)